# How do I correctly test asynchronous stream error event handling with mocha/sinon/chai?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js

I am testing an async method that returns some data from a web request using the native https.request() method in NodeJS.  I am using mocha, chai, and sinon with the relevant extensions for each.

The method I'm testing essentially wraps the boilerplate https.request() code provided in the NodeJS docs in a Promise and resolves when the response 'end' event is received or rejects if the request 'error' event is received.  The bits relevant to discussion look like this:

```
async fetch(...) {
    // setup

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = https.request(url, opts, (res) => {
            // handle response events
        });
        
        req.on('error', (e) => {
            logger.error(e);  // <-- this is what i want to verify
            reject(e);
        });

        req.end();
    });
}
```

As indicated in the comment, what I want to test is that if the request error event is emitted, the error gets logged correctly.  This is what I'm currently doing to achieve this:

```
it('should log request error events', async () => {
    const sut = new MyService();
    const err = new Error('boom');
    const req = new EventEmitter();
    req.end = sinon.fake();
    const res = new EventEmitter();
    sinon.stub(logger, 'error');
    sinon.stub(https, 'request').callsFake((url, opt, cb) => {
        cb(res);
        return req;
    });

    try {
        const response = sut.fetch(...);
        req.emit('error', err);
        await response;
    } catch() {}

    logger.error.should.have.been.calledOnceWith(err);
});
```

This feels like a hack, but I can't figure out how to do this correctly using the normal patterns.  The main problem is I need to emit the error event after the method is called but before the promise is fulfilled, and I can't see how to do that if I am returning the promise as you normally would with mocha.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this. You might alternatively want to put a `setTimeout(() => req.emit('error', err), demoDelay);` inside the `request` fake, and then write `await sut.fetch(…);`, but either way is fine.

Comment: What do you refer to when you say "*I can't see how to do that if I am returning the promise as you normally would with mocha.*"? Your `async` function *does* return a promise to mocha.

Comment: @Bergi Your setTimeout idea gave me the answer I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I should have thought of this, but @Bergi's comment about using setTimeout() in the fake gave me an idea and I now have this working with the preferred syntax:

```
it('should log request error events', () => {
    const sut = new MyService();
    const err = new Error('boom');
    const req = new EventEmitter();
    req.end = sinon.fake();
    const res = new EventEmitter();
    sinon.stub(logger, 'error');
    sinon.stub(https, 'request').callsFake((url, opt, cb) => {
        cb(res);
        setTimeout(() => { req.emit('error', err); });
        return req;
    });

    return sut.fetch(...).should.eventually.be.rejectedWith(err)
        .then(() => {
            logger.error.should.have.been.calledOnceWith(err);
        });
});
```

I don't like adding any delays in unit tests unless I'm specifically testing delayed functionality, so I used setTimeout() with 0 delay just to push the emit call to the end of the message queue.  By moving it to the fake I was able to just use promise chaining to test the call to the logger method.

Comment: Your original code is using promise chaining as well, the only difference is that it's storing the promise in a temporary variable `response`. I'd think that using `async`/`await` syntax for chaining instead of `.then()` calls would be preferred?

Comment: @Bergi I am still learning, but I think I see your point in what is actually happening behind the scenes.  In the original code, even though the logger check is a separate statement, since it's an async function the statements after an await are chained the same as if you called then().  This is pretty insightful, thanks!  And yes, in normal code I  prefer async/await, but in the case of unit tests I am trying to maintain a consistent BDD style, so this version reads more like the other tests, even if there's little underlying difference.